# Uniswap mint() transaction fails in Goerli

Tags: python, ethereum, uniswap

I want to use a python library to mint liquidity in the Goerli testnet.

Using a forked mainnet, [uniswap-python](https://uniswap-python.com/api.html) works, with command `uniswap.mint_liquidity()`.

That fails when I switch to Goerli.

So, I try [web3.py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

First, I approve like so. This works:

```
approval_data = token_0_instance.encodeABI(fn_name='approve', args=[nft_manager.address, amt])
transaction = {...}
signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, pk)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
```

Then, I want to use `mint` from the NFT position manager, right? This fails:

```
mint_params = (
...tuple of mint_params...
)

transaction = {
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(account),
    'to': nft_manager.address, 
    'data': nft_manager.functions.mint(mint_params).transact(),  
    'gas': gas,  
    'gasPrice': w3.to_wei('500', 'gwei'), 
}

signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, pk)
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
```

The above fails. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

The second snippet fails also in forked mainnet.

UPDATE: the line that fails is

`nft_manager.functions.mint(mint_params).transact()`

Comment: What error message/details of the failure do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @LucasHendren Thanks for the response. As per the update above, the line that doesn't work is `nft_manager.functions.mint(mint_params).transact()` The error is :File /opt/anaconda3/envs/uswap/lib/python3.11/site-packages/web3/_utils/contract_error_handling.py:135, in raise_contract_logic_error_on_revert(response)
    133 # Geth Revert without error message case:
    134 if "execution reverted" in response["error"].get("message"):
--> 135     raise ContractLogicError("execution reverted", data=data)
    137 return response

ContractLogicError: execution reverted

Comment: You can use [this](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/core/_autosummary/eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason.html#eth_defi.revert_reason.fetch_transaction_revert_reason) and [this](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/core/_autosummary/eth_defi.trace.assert_transaction_success_with_explanation.html#eth_defi.trace.assert_transaction_success_with_explanation) functions to get the know the reason why your transaction fails in web3.py code. Alternatively you can use a web transaction debugger like [tenderly.co](https://tenderly.co/).